# query postgres for distinction across two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a database with the following table

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3  |  
 A   | C     | data1
 A   | B     | data2
 B   | A     | data3
 A   | D     | data4
 C   | A     | data5
```

I need a query that will select all distinct rows across Col1 and Col2 (So AC == CA), but I need to count the total.

So my return might be like

```
Combo| Count
AC | 2
AB | 2
AD | 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a simple aggregation query with a twist because the ordering is not important:

```
select least(col1, col2) || greatest(col1, col2), count(*) as cnt
from t
group by least(col1, col2) || greatest(col1, col2);
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks! That's way simpler than what I had been doing - trying to union two selections from the same table.